# Invalid pdf structure issue in React project.(I am using pdfjs)

Tags: reactjs, pdfjs-dist

I am using pdfjs to read pdf files in react app. I tested several pdf files but the browser still shows "Invalid pdf structure" message.
This is the code which I tried.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Viewer, Worker } from '@react-pdf-viewer/core';
import { defaultLayoutPlugin } from '@react-pdf-viewer/default-layout';

import '@react-pdf-viewer/core/lib/styles/index.css';
import '@react-pdf-viewer/default-layout/lib/styles/index.css';

export default function Trial() {
    const defaultLayoutPluginInstance = defaultLayoutPlugin();

    return (
        <Worker workerUrl="https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@2.15.349/build/pdf.worker.js">
            <div
                style={{
                    height: '750px',
                    width: '900px',
                    marginLeft: 'auto',
                    marginRight: 'auto',
                }}
            >
                <Viewer
                    fileUrl='./test.pdf'
                    plugins={[defaultLayoutPluginInstance]}
                />
            </div>
        </Worker>
    );
};
```

The pdf file is a standard type. (I got this when I installed acrobat so I suppose so.)

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether there are errors in browser devtool console, network requests. If you can open the file successful in https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html, then the file is valid. `Invalid pdf structure` shows the file didn't parsed by the worker properly somehow, maybe it didn't download the file, maybe the worker didn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks again, KJ, Priestch. I installed identical version(old) but it still showed error. I solved this by just using iframe tag.